# Trigger a Cloud Run Build/Deploy with a remote Trigger/Webhookin Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, webhooks, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-run

I've current got a NextJS app connected that I would like to migrate over to Google Cloud Run.

Right now, the sight is *majority* static generated pages--in the build process `next` does static generation and discovery for most of the pages.  These pages often don't update for weeks at a time.

While hosting it on Vercel, I was able to setup the app to rebuild and deploy whenever a webhook was triggered.  This allowed the site to rebuild and generate all the static pages if a copy change was made, without needing to push something to Github or push a button.

We're looking to move a lot of our work over to GCP soon, and I'm looking to see how I can replicate this functionality.  Currently, the only trigger I can set within GCP Console seems to be a push/commit event for the attached repo--nothing else.

I'm not sure if this is possible?  It appears that Azure and AWS both have the ability to setup triggers based on webhooks, but as far as I can tell that feature is completely absent in GCP.

The only thing I can think of is setting up a cloud function or making a consumer for the CMS webhook that will make and empty commit and push it to trigger a rebuild--but I'm hoping there's **SOMETHING** more sane out there than this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud run is much more flexible that a cloud function (and a bit more expensive unless you can run it concurrently) and you can test locally your microservice.

You can trigger cloud run:

- From an HTTPS get/post (it will use a special URL)
- From cloud build.
- From a pub/sub message (wich can be also generated by google cloud storage notification - just drop/update/delete a file).

You might find this useful:

1 -  Codelab (google cloud tutorial) [Cloud Run Hello](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-run-hello#0) - deploying a NodeJS app in Cloud Run.

2 - This google blog post [Using Cloud Run as a Webhook for Actions](https://medium.com/google-developers/using-cloud-run-as-a-webhook-for-actions-on-google-792b58694651) it's a Java code example; but ilustrates very well how to work with Cloud Run.

3 - This might be similar to your use case: [Automatic Deployment of Hugo Sites on Firebase Hosting and Drafts on Cloud Run](https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/automatic-deployment-of-hugo-sites-on-firebase-hosting.html)

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding--your first link is about **making** a cloud run project INTO a Webhook, and the second example is still just using Google's "push to github" trigger--which doesn't help here :/

I'm trying to figure out how to start a rebuild/redeploy of a container on Cloud Run, using a webhook or other **non-git** external action

Comment: If you work with Cloud build, you can trigger a rebuild via API without touching the repo. See https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds/create

Comment: Ah, there we go!  That is what i was looking for.  This is super helpful, thank you!